# How send notification from the library to the app

Tags: android, notifications

I have created a library, which can send push notifications to an android application. When i put all the code of library to the application, it works but when I try to run them separately, the application doesn't receive any notifications.

The implementation of this function:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(content);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        String bootrapClassName = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance(this).getClassNameClient();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(bootrapClassName));

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Class.forName(bootrapClassName));
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(DcarBeaconApplication.NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

There is no error or exception, it works fine but doesn't receive any notifications. Please suggest me how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: did you defined receiver in your manifest file?

Comment: @sasikumar: thanks for asking. not yet, have you any suggest for this receiver.

Comment: where have you created this library?

Comment: @Jordan: the library is a module in Android Studio project. Another one is an application.

Comment: So you have two modules of the same application which are sending push notifications to each other. Right?

Comment: @Jordan: No, i have only one library, and the application is just for testing notification of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try and test some cases, finally, i have to create a service of the library to send the broadcast to the application, and in the application, i register a receiver to listener the service, and to push notification directly from the application.